# Why are people afraid of things that they know are harmless or non-existent?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, anxiety, fear

Why are people afraid of things that they know are harmless or non-existent? For example:
Why do horror films/stories leave people scared after they have finished?
Someone may see a harmless spider somewhere that isn't even on their property, and still be scared of it. What is the phenomenon behind this?

Comment: The question mixes several distinct phenomena together and needs a clearer focus: (1) A movie with potentially real events (psychopathic murderer killing you) will remind you of that real danger. Fear is a natural reaction to witnessing a fearful event. [It has been shown that people today are more afraid of becoming victims of statistically rare crimes, because media represent them as happening constantly everywhere.] (2) Being afraid of a "harmless" spider seems an evolutionary remnant. Many spiders aren't harmless. (3) Being afraid of the dark might be due to a loss of perception. etc.

Comment: I'd like to try and help you clarify this question if you'd like. Please feel free to ping me in chat if you'd like. For now, I've put it on hold.